# Index of array return -1

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have one issue, I what to know index of clicked row. I have tried the below code but it returned -1 for every single row.

Here is sample code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".row-parent", function(){

    var param = $("#inputKeyword").val();

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://xxxxxxxxx:8040/services/search/"+param,
    //data:{ keyword: param},
    }).done(function(data){

        var data=data.result;
        alert(data.length);

        var index = $(this).index(data);
        alert("Index: "+index);

    });
});
```

Comment: `this` in the context of your `done` function is the function scope, not the `$(document).on()` scope.

Answer (score 0):

As @jsve wrote:

> `this` in the context of your done function is the function scope, not the `$(document).on()` scope.

Your code should be:

```
$(document).on("click", ".row-parent", function(){

    var param = $("#inputKeyword").val();
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://xxxxxxxxx:8040/services/search/"+param,
    //data:{ keyword: param},
    }).done(function(data){

        var data=data.result;
        alert(data.length);

        var index = $(that).index(data);
        alert("Index: "+index);

    });
});
```

Comment: Still returned -1 @Gothdo